# jquery after select event

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery tabs, each tab has variable heights.
When I select a tab I need to refresh the content in a div to accomodate the window scroll appearing/disappearing.

Looking at the API documentation for the tabs plugin there is load event and a select event. I cannot seem to find any other events I can plug into.

The load event works fine but when selecting a tab that is already loaded the select event fires before the content is displayed.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    cache: false,
    select: function (e, ui) {
        // running the event here will not work as it runs before the content is diplayed
    },
    load: function (event, ui){
        // running it here works ok as it fires the event after the content is displayed
    }
});
```

I need the event to fire after the content is displayed.

Is there an event I can plug into for this particular behaviour?

Comment: Which version of jqueryUI are you using?

Comment: Hmm. I'm sure I'm looking at the same [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/) you are.  If the `show` event doesn't work, maybe you can just configure a timer in the `select` handler to fire off 250 ms later?  Not a real solution, but if it gets the job done...

Comment: Perfect! thanks, put this as answer for me please so I can mark it as the resolution. This was the API I was looking at: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JqueryUI 1.8 API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/) describes the `show` and `select` events.

If `show` doesn't work, then perhaps configuring a timer in the `select` handler to refresh the div a few milliseconds later will do the trick.